# How to vectorize complex cumulative aggregation problem?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, aggregation, stock

Dataset:

| date | time_index | identifier | value | cum_value | bar_index | desired_output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | 1 | stackoverflow | 5 | 5 | NaN | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 2 | stackoverflow | 10 | 15 | NaN | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 3 | stackoverflow | 10 | 25 | NaN | 1 |
| 2023-06-01 | 1 | cross_validated | 4 | 4 | NaN | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 2 | cross_validated | 6 | 10 | NaN | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 3 | cross_validated | 20 | 30 | NaN | 1 |
| 2023-06-01 | 4 | cross_validated | 5 | 35 | NaN | 2 |
| 2023-06-02 | 1 | stackoverflow | 2 | 2 | NaN | 0 |
| 2023-06-02 | 2 | stackoverflow | 10 | 12 | NaN | 0 |
| 2023-06-02 | 1 | cross_validated | 20 | 20 | NaN | 0 |
| 2023-06-02 | 2 | cross_validated | 3 | 23 | NaN | 1 |
| 2023-06-02 | 3 | cross_validated | 3 | 26 | NaN | 1 |

Code that generates the dataset:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ["2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-02", "2023-06-02", "2023-06-02", "2023-06-02", "2023-06-02"],
    "time_index": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    "identifier": ["stackoverflow", "stackoverflow", "stackoverflow", "cross_validated", "cross_validated", "cross_validated", "cross_validated", 
               "stackoverflow", "stackoverflow", "cross_validated", "cross_validated", "cross_validated"],
    "value": [5, 10, 10, 4, 6, 20, 5, 2, 10, 20, 3, 3]
})
df["cum_value"] = df.groupby(["identifier", "date"])["value"].cumsum()
df["bar_index"] = np.nan
df["desired_output"] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I want to sample `bar_index` for each `identifier` and `date` according to a fixed (for now) threshold `τ`=10, using a column's `value` and/or `cum_value`.

- `τ` = 10
- date: 2023-06-01 = `d1` & 2023-06-02 = `d2`
- identifier: stackoverflow = `id1` & cross_validated = `id2`
- time_index ∈ `{t1, t2,...,tn} ∀ d, id`

1. Observation {id1, d1, t1} has a value less than the threshold of 10 so we continue to the next entries. If we add the `value` of {id1, d1, t1} and {id1, d1, t2} together we reach a `cum_value` (cumulative value) of 15, which exceeds the threshold. Therefore we would sample {id1, d1, t1} as well as {id1, d1, t2} as `bar_index` 0.
2. If we encounter an observation with a very large value (for example {id2, d1, t3}) and the previous bar ended (cumulative value exceeded the threshold from the last trade), we would sample this observation along as a `bar_index`. The next observation starts a new accumulation (in theory).

Current non-vectorized approach:

```py
def aggregate_bars(group, threshold):
    cum_value = 0
    bar_index = 0

    for i in range(len(group)):
        cum_value += group.iloc[i]["value"]
        if cum_value >= threshold:
            group["bar_index"].iloc[i] = bar_index
            bar_index += 1
            cum_value = 0
        elif cum_value < threshold:
            group["bar_index"].iloc[i] = bar_index

    return group

df = df.groupby(["identifier", "date"]).apply(lambda x: aggregate_bars(x, 10))
df
```

Output:

| date | time_index | identifier | value | cum_value | bar_index | desired_output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | 1 | stackoverflow | 5 | 5 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 2 | stackoverflow | 10 | 15 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 3 | stackoverflow | 10 | 25 | 1.0 | 1 |
| 2023-06-01 | 1 | cross_validated | 4 | 4 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 2 | cross_validated | 6 | 10 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 3 | cross_validated | 20 | 30 | 1.0 | 1 |
| 2023-06-01 | 4 | cross_validated | 5 | 35 | 2.0 | 2 |
| 2023-06-02 | 1 | stackoverflow | 2 | 2 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-02 | 2 | stackoverflow | 10 | 12 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-02 | 1 | cross_validated | 20 | 20 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-02 | 2 | cross_validated | 3 | 23 | 1.0 | 1 |
| 2023-06-02 | 3 | cross_validated | 3 | 26 | 1.0 | 1 |

How to vectorize the code so it can effectively process trillions of rows?

Comment: Not really clear. 1) According to the question, `cum_dollar_vol` is defined as `size * price`. But isn't `cum_dollar_vol` the `cumsum` of `dollar`? 2) Also, how is the `dollar` column e.g. for the above trade 0 calculated (500,000)? The column isn't given in the first snippet. 3) Are there typos in `aggregate_trades`? One parameter is `dollar_col`, but it is never used (perhaps `dollar_vol` is meant? 4) Could you provide example data for some tickers and dates where the expected output can be calculated using `aggregate_trades`?

Comment: @KevinLi I'm not able to reproduce your desired result using the non-vectorised version. I get `[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

Comment: I think the key to this is the strange cumsum you have created. The values within the function don't actually correspond to the column values

Comment: you might want to look at `np.vectorize` OP

Comment: @Mark Note that `np.vectorize` does not actually "vectorize" anything. It's just syntactic sugar for a loop: ["The *vectorize* function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Comment: I'm not sure this function can be vectorized because the condition `if cum_value >= threshold` depends on computation done in the previous row. However, it can be made significantly faster by cleaning it up a bit. Depending on how large each group is, maybe numba would make it even faster.

Comment: @Mark I testsed the code again and there is no issue with the output. Can you please check carefully if you have copied the codes correctly? Thanks. I think you can try to pass in group_keys=False parameter when calling the df groupby if you get different outputs.

Comment: @cottontail Thank you for your suggestion. The reason why I must vectorize this operation is that I am using university funded HPC for my research and I have trillions of rows and thousands of groups. I must use Rapids workflow to accelerate the process by multiple GPUs. In addition, it is true that the cum_value refreshing bevahiour makes it particularly challenging to vectorize. I believe there must be some kind of value manipulation as a fucntion of the threshold to help with the incrementing and sampling. For example, if the value is greater than the threshold bring it down to the threshol

Comment: I uploaded a Excel file detailing my thoughts where you can find via this link: https://utoronto-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/kevinyangfan_li_mail_utoronto_ca/EW_wAVe1sDVClR0NckVaSxgBCQJConPFZTyM-vKbGJVb6A
Please comment if you have any more questions

Comment: I think the fact that `bar_index` value persists even if cumsum is reset depending on an if-clause precludes this function to be vectorized. That said, the current function is so slow because it loops over a DataFrame object. If you make it loop over a Series, or better a Python list, then it will be much faster.

Comment: @cottontail It will indeed be very fast but still significantly slower than Cudf vectorization. The parameter of the sampling (threshold) will be tweaked in an iterative process, which would be highly time consuming by any kind of loops

Comment: Maybe we can manipulate the cumulative value while not resetting it to fit the desired range of integer division by the threshold which determines the bar index?

Comment: @KevinLi I think it is because of weird grouping. For example, in your code, you group by identifier, then date, but the markdown table shows date, then identifier

Comment: but also the cumsum in the column isn't the actual cumsum used. You might want to remove that, it's misleading. The real cumsum resets to 0 everytime cumsum + value >= threshold

Comment: I thought of using integer division by the threshold but that wouldn't work for values such as `[9,9,12]`. I reckon it's not possible to write a function faster than a loop. If anyone comes up with a vectorized function that is faster than a loop, I'll give 200 rep bounty.

Comment: I would actually get rid of groupby altogether and write a bare Python loop and decorate it with numba jit.

Comment: @cottontail I appreciate your great efforts. Numba would be my last line of defence when it comes to implementation. Thank you. On the other hand, can you please take look at my file shared in last comments? My 3 helpers approach is very close but not quite there. I believe the path is promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that your function can be vectorised *exactly* as stated. Your choice for element `i` depends directly on your choice for `i-1`, in a way that you cannot really shuffle around any computation. Depending on what your goal is with these values, it may be a good solution to find an alternative function that gets the job done and is vectorised more readily.

That does not mean, however, that this function cannot be improved and sped up.

#### Initial ideas: Binary search

First, the `cumsum` operation *can* be vectorised, and doing so will remove a whole bunch of Python function calls, doing it all in C.

Next, instead of doing a linear search for the next location where the bar overflows, we can make it a binary search. Numpy has an implementation for that.

```py
def _binary_search_get_bar_index(cumsum, threshold):
  bar_index = 0
  covered_count = 0
  covered_sum = 0
  result = np.zeros_like(cumsum)
  l = len(cumsum)
  while True:
    bar_last = np.searchsorted(cumsum, covered_sum + threshold)
    result[covered_count:min(bar_last + 1, l)] = bar_index
    bar_index += 1
    covered_count = bar_last + 1
    if covered_count >= l:
      break
    covered_sum = cumsum[bar_last]
  return result


def binary_search(df, threshold):
  cumsum = df["value"].cumsum()
  df['bar_index'] = _binary_search_get_bar_index(cumsum.values, threshold)
  return df
```

#### Numba

Before jumping into benchmarking, I thought I'd also implement your original function (shuffled around a bit), and decorating it with `numba.njit`. This compiles machine code based on the python function. Almost as if pandas had it implemented for you in C.

```py
@njit
def _numba_get_bar_index(cumsum, threshold):
  covered_sum = 0
  bar_index = 0
  result = np.zeros_like(cumsum)
  for i in range(len(cumsum)):
    result[i] = bar_index
    if cumsum[i] >= covered_sum + threshold:
      bar_index += 1
      covered_sum = cumsum[i]
  return result


def numba_f(df, threshold):
  cumsum = df["value"].cumsum()
  df['bar_index'] = _numba_get_bar_index(cumsum.values, threshold)
  return df
```

#### Setup

I verified that both of these solutions give exactly the desired output on your dataset in the question.

I benchmarked on a DataFrame with 100 000 rows, running on an M1 Pro Mac.

The data was generated as below. I omitted irrelevant columns. I also omitted grouping as it's also not relevant to the question, your original function simply receives a DataFrame and only reads the `values` column.

```py
long_data = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.default_rng().poisson(8, 100000)})
# long_data.head() -> [6, 14, 8, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 10]
```

#### Results

```
%timeit original(long_data, 10)
7 s ± 49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%timeit binary_search(long_data, 10)
82.2 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
%timeit numba_f(long_data, 10)
433 µs ± 5.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

It turns out that simply using numba can give you really strong gains (over four orders of magnitude in this case). The magic of having things nearby in cache and not jumping around a lot in memory for different function calls and pointer dereferences.

Actually, as the complexity in big O terms is always going to be dominated by computing the cumsum, I can't imagine a scenario, where the binary search would win out. It is also unlikely that you could get anything significantly better than the numba result.

Comment: I tested my code with this thing on my HPC today with only one node, pure CPU, for a small dataset of 1.5 Billion rows. The whole operation took about 7.5 miniutes, which is super impressive. Can you let me know a bit how it can achieve that?

Comment: The runtime is acceptable. Now the question is that I have to use groupby aggregation for applying the numba function with seperate groups:
```ticks["threshold"] = threshold
ticks = ticks.groupby(["ticker", "date"], group_keys=False, sort=True).apply(lambda x: numba_f(x))
```
How can I get rid of the groupby aggregation all along?