# Polars groupby map UDF using multiple columns as parameter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numba, python-polars

I have a numba UDF:

```py
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def generate_sample_numba(cumulative_dollar_volume: np.ndarray, dollar_tau: Union[int, np.ndarray]) -> np.ndarray:
        """ Generate the sample using numba for speed.
        """
        covered_dollar_volume = 0
        bar_index = 0
        bar_index_array = np.zeros_like(cumulative_dollar_volume, dtype=np.uint32)
        
        if isinstance(dollar_tau, int):
            dollar_tau = np.array([dollar_tau] * len(cumulative_dollar_volume))

        for i in range(len(cumulative_dollar_volume)):
            bar_index_array[i] = bar_index
            if cumulative_dollar_volume[i] >= covered_dollar_volume + dollar_tau[i]:
                bar_index += 1
                covered_dollar_volume = cumulative_dollar_volume[i]
        return bar_index_array
```

The UDF takes two inputs:

1. The `cumulative_dollar_volume` numpy array, which is essentially the groups in `group_by`
2. The `dollar_tau` threshold, which is either an *integer* or *numpy array*.

In this question, I am particularly interested in the numpy array configuration. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683540/how-to-vectorize-complex-cumulative-aggregation-problem) well explains the idea behind the `generat_sample_numba` function.

I want to achieve the same results from Pandas by **using polars**:

```py
data["bar_index"] = data.groupby(["ticker", "date"]).apply(lambda x: generate_sample_numba(x["cumulative_dollar_volume"].values, x["dollar_tau"].values)).explode().values.astype(int)
```

Apprently, the best option in Polars is by `group_by().agg(pl.col().map_batehces()`:

```py
cqt_sample = cqt_sample.with_columns(
    (pl.col("price") * pl.col("size")).alias("dollar_volume")).with_columns(
    pl.col("dollar_volume").cum_sum().over(["ticker", "date"]).alias("cumulative_dollar_volume"),
    pl.lit(1_000_000).alias("dollar_tau")
    )

(cqt_sample
    .group_by(["ticker", "date"])
    .agg(pl.col(["cumulative_dollar_volume", "dollar_tau"])
         .map_batches(lambda x: generate_sample_numba(x["cumulative_dollar_volume"].to_numpy(), 1_000_000))
                      )#.alias("bar_index")
                      )#.explode("bar_index")
```

but the `map_bathces()` method seems to throw some strange results.`

However, when I use the integer `dollar_tau` with one input column it works fine:

```py
(cqt_sample
    .group_by(["ticker", "date"])
    .agg(pl.col("cumulative_dollar_volume")
         .map_batches(lambda x: generate_sample_numba(x.to_numpy(), 1_000_000))
                      ).alias("bar_index")
                      ).explode("bar_index")
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the problem is. The only information we currently have is *"strange results"*. Can you provide `cqt_sample` in order to make your example runnable, along with the expected output?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, you can find 3 days of raw cqt datasets [here](https://utoronto-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/kevinyangfan_li_mail_utoronto_ca/EhP528f2g5FIllAkDJqFD44BUnCI3TFCWdZB_hrCLgxh5w?e=ECGxxt). 

In terms of “strange results” I am getting two columns of lists: cumulative dollar volume and dollar tau transformed by the UDF. However, the dollar tau is supposed to help the UDF to determine the threshold.

Comment: I would use “ticker” for the identifier and [“TSLA”, “MMM”, LCFY.W”] for testing.

Comment: Thank you for the links but that is a lot of data. Just a small 10-row sample to make your code runnable should be enough to show the issue. As for the problem `pl.col("a", "b").map_batches` is shorthand for `pl.col("a").map_batches, pl.col("b").map_batches` - but you want to pass multiple items at the same time so would likely need a struct: `pl.struct("a", "b").map_batches`

Comment: Function names have since changed, but it's essentially this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71679606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you'll need to call [`pl.Expr.map_batches`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_batches.html) on a [struct](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/structs/) column that contains all information needed by the function. Inside the function, you then pick the struct apart to obtain the desired information.

```py
(
    data
    .group_by(["ticker", "date"])
    .agg(
        pl.struct("cumulative_dollar_volume", "dollar_tau").map_batches(lambda x: \
            generate_sample_numba(
                x.struct.field("cumulative_dollar_volume").to_numpy(),
                dollar_tau=x.struct.field("dollar_tau").to_numpy()
            )
        )
        .alias("bar_index")
    )
).explode("bar_index")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does ‘maintain order’ do in the groupby function? Can I get away without using it? In addition, why do we explode by cumulative dollar volume at the end? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLi `maintain_order=True` ensures that the order of the groups is consistent with the input data, i.e. if ticker `A` came before ticker `B` in the input, the same is true for the output.

Comment: @KevinLi As we don't assign an alias to the column created by `map_batches`, it will automatically be named `"cumulative_dollar_volume"` (as it is the first column used in the expression). The returned column will be a list column that contains the samples. `explode` is then used to obtain a separate row for each sample.

Comment: If I sort the output dataframe I will still get the same results by not passing ‘maintain_order’ right? While this option enables streaming.

Comment: For the column Alias, is it possible that we name the output column generated by the match_batches method?

Comment: @KevinLi If the dataframe was sorted by the group column before using `group_by`, sorting afterwards will give the same result as `maintain_order=True`, yes.

Comment: @KevinLi Sure, you can add `.alias("new_name")` at the end of the expression within `.agg` and, then, use `.explode("new_name")`.

Comment: @KevinLi I've approved the suggested edit and included the alias. However, I've removed the final `sort` as it is not really contributing the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

The origianl apporach is to apply the `map_bathces` method with `group_by` where a new DataFrame would be genreated. However, if we still want to access the information from the original DataFrame, the windows function is a lot better choice, instead of merging the newly generated column(s) to the original one:

```py
udf_expression = (
    pl.struct(["cumulative_volume", self.volume_tau])
    .map_batches(lambda x: self.generate_sample_numba(x.struct.field("cumulative_volume").to_numpy(), x.struct.field(self.volume_tau).to_numpy()))
    .over([self.identifier_col, self.date_col])
    .alias("bar_index")
    )

data = (data
        .filter(self.cqt_filter)
        .with_columns(
            pl.col(self.size_col).cum_sum().over([self.identifier_col, self.date_col]).alias("cumulative_volume")
            )
        .with_columns(udf_expression))
```